# Resize video player and give it different video urls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, flash, jwplayer

I have many video thumbnails and I'm trying to display the original video-player above the thumbnails when someone clicks on the thumbnail. I'm using jwplayer and I want to display the original video when the thumbnail is clicked. By giving the div the video url and by making the jwplayer visible and resize it to 100%.

When someone clicks at the button I want the player to get hidden with a width and height of 0% ( to prevent margin or whitespace over the thumbnails.) By clicking on the different thumbnails the video url changes and gets hidden or displayed.
This code does not work. Does anyone have any idea?

I have all the divs defined.

**Here is the Jquery**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $(".popup_link2").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#video").html( jwplayer('video').attr('file', $(this).attr("href")) );
            jwplayer("video").resize('100%', '400');
         });
      });

   $(document).ready(function() {
         $(".btn").click(function() {
          jwplayer("video").resize('0', '0');
      });
    });
```

**Here is the jwplayer. And the Divs.**

```
<div class="thumball"> 
  <% @project.assets.each do |asset1| %>
  <% if asset1.video.file? %>
    <li class="thumbnail span1 col-md-2" id="thumb2" style="border: none; float: none; display: inline-block !important; float: none !important; position: relative;">
      <%= link_to asset1.video.url(:orginal), class: :popup_link2, target: :_blank do %>
      <div class="picture1">
       <span class="roll" ></span>
       </div>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      jwplayer("video").setup({
          flashplayer: "<%=asset_path('jwplayer.flash.swf')%>",
          file: '<%= asset1.video.url(:original) %>',
          primary: "flash",
          height: 0,
          width: 0,
          analytics: {
              enabled: false,
             cookies: false
         }
      });

    </script> 
  <% end %>
  </li>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe use our API and resize? http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/29411/resizing-the-player/